# Reading 2 Values from a list Flutter

Tags: list, flutter

How can i read 2 in 2 values from a list of 10 values? Like, i want to create 5 another lists that have 2 in 2 values of the main list. I'm thinking about use for like that
I don't want to do that manually because i will have more values in the future, like 100. I know i can use index of list to get the value but how to get 2 values like, index 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, etc

```
List teste = dados["moodGraph"];
                for(int i = 0; i <= teste.length; i++){
                  List teste2 = teste[i];
                }
```

but i don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
List<List> duoList = [];
    List teste = dados["moodGraph"];
    for (int i = 0; i < teste.length - 1; i += 2) {
      duoList.add([
        teste[i],
        [teste[i + 1]]
      ]);
    }
```